# Como pegar o valor de um id que é incremental e usá-lo como chave estrangeira sem usar set/get?

Tags: java, sql

Eu tenho uma primary key e precisava usá-la em uma outra tabela como FK, como faço para inserir no banco de uma forma que não precise usar os modificadores set ou get?

Comment: Tá complicado de entender o que você quer. Edita tua pergunta.

Comment: Qual é o banco? qual é o framework de persistência? precianos de mais detalhes. =D